# How can i Access service Identities from one ACS name space with another ACS name space

Tags: azure, acs, acs-serviceidentity

i have an Relying Party applications that trust ACS Namespace A, and I have Service Identities in ACS Namespace B, and i want the Service Identities to be able to call those Relying Party applications so that Namespace A talks to Namespace B to get authenticated.

is there any way to implement this, i was unable to find any documents related to this, if any one can guide me to some documentation on how we can implement this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is doable but a bit convoluted. You need namespace A to be added as an RP to namespace B, and namespace B to be added as an IdP to namespace A (both can be added via WS-Federation metadata). You'll also need some special rules.

In namespace B, you need a rule of Issuer ACS (LOCAL AUTHORITY if using the management service), NameID SIName, pass through. In Namespace A, you'll need a rule of Issuer NamespaceB, NameID SIName, pass through (you could also pass through all NameIDs here).

Once you're set up, the flow looks like this.

1. Client requests a token from namespace B using the OAuth2 protocol. The RP of this request is NamespaceA.
2. Client receives this token and presents it to namespace A. The RP of this request is the actual RP you want.

Assuming everything is configured correctly, the token that the client receives in (2) will grant it access to your RP.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what are you asking!

ACS is a `passive` service! There is no such process like `Service Identities to be able to call those Relying Party applications`! **Service Identity** is a way to authenticate **Active Clients** - these server side processes that do not invoke user interaction.

If you want to be able to **authenticate** in **Relying Party X** both with **[IdP via ACS Namespace A]** and **Server side code identified by Service Identity in ACS Namespace B**, then you just need to establish trust relationship between **Relying Party X* and both ACS Namespaces.

You cannot use ACS Namespace as an **Identity Provider** for another ACS Namespace. Which is what I understand you want to achieve.

Comment: ACS is not only passive. In addition to its passive endpoints, it supports active endpoints such as OAuth 2.0, and WS-Trust. Additionally, it's definitely possible to use one ACS namespace as an IdP for another namespace in either passive or active flows.

Comment: I thought I mentioned (and it is in BOLD) - **Active clients**. When I say `passive service` I mean that it is not `Azure Active Directory` per se. It is more just a federation service with some options for `active protocols` like ws-trust. But as we talk about web-app and web user flow, ws-trust is automatically dropped off the conversation. And a note for ACS - exposing the WS-Federation endpoint in `Application Integration` would have saved a lot of headaches!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your comment a little bit. My assumption from the original question is that this is an active scenario because of the use of Service Identities. 

As for not listing WS-Fed in Application Integration, this is because you can get that address via Fed Metadata, which is listed. WS-Trust is not listed there for the same reason.

Comment: Just tested - indeed I can use `ACS NS A` as IdP for `ACS NS B`. Never thought of such scenario, but it works just fine with WS-Federation - i.e. pure web app scenario.
Interesting point for WS-Fed endpoint. True indeed, but still one more step ("click"=>"search"=>"copy" instead of just "copy") when integrating ACS with 3rd parties like ADFS or IdentityServer via WS-Federation.

Comment: The intent is that you'd use fed metadata and therefore wouldn't need to know the actual endpoint URL. You can do this when federating with other ACS namespaces or with ADFS. I recognize that this doesn't work for every partner, though.

Any number of scenarios involving multiple ACS instances, WAAD, or ADFS, can be accomplished. This is the beauty of open standards!